# Shell script command help to shorten?

Tags: shell, awk, ssh, netstat

I have a command that is like this:

```
/bin/netstat -an | /usr/bin/awk -vmax=100 '/tcp/{split($5,a,":"); if(a[1] > 0 && a[1]!="0.0.0.0" && a[1]!="127.0.0.1" && a[1]!="111.222.111.222" ... 50 addresses... && a[1]!="211.112.211.112"){c[a[1]]++}} END{for(ip in c){if(c[ip]>max){print ip}}}' | while read ip; do /sbin/iptables -m comment --comment "SCAN BLOCK" -I INPUT 1 -s $ip -j DROP; done
```

How can I  shorten it to read IP addresses from file, or from a array list above command, or something like that as I have now almost 100 IPs and all are one next to another in one big command line.

Basicaly, how to make command something like this:

```
/bin/netstat -an | /usr/bin/awk -vmax=100 '/tcp/{split($5,a,":"); if(a[1] > 0 && a[1]!="read from file"){c[a[1]]++}} END{for(ip in c){if(c[ip]>max){print ip}}}' | while read ip; do /sbin/iptables -m comment --comment "SCAN BLOCK" -I INPUT 1 -s $ip -j DROP; done
```

Comment: `while read line; do <your stuff> ; done < ip_list.txt` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the list of ips in a file, eg:

```
$ cat iplist.txt
0.0.0.0
127.0.0.1
111.222.111.222
... snip ...
211.112.211.112
```

The general approach is to have `awk` process 2 input files with different logic, eg:

```
/bin/netstat -an | 
/usr/bin/awk -vmax=100 '

# process 1st file (iplist.txt): 

FNR==NR { iplist[$1]                 # FNR==NR is only true for the 1st file; for follow-on files FNR resets to 1 but NR keeps increasing
          next                       # skip to next input record; keeps from running follow-on code against 1st file contents
        }   

# process 2nd file (stdin):

/tcp/   { split($5,a,":")
          if (a[1] > 0 && !(a[1] in iplist))
             c[a[1]]++
        }
END     { for (ip in c) 
              if (c[ip]>max)
                 print ip
        }
' iplist.txt -                      # 2nd file actually says to read from stdin (ie, output from netstat call)
```

**NOTE:** OP would then pipe this output to the same `while/iptables` loop, eg:

```
/bin/netstat -an | 
/usr/bin/awk -vmax=100 '
FNR==NR { iplist[$1] 
... snip ...
                 print ip
        }
' iplist.txt - |  while read ip; do /sbin/iptables ...;done

# or collapsed to one line (though harder to read and/or troubleshoot):

netstat -an | awk -vmax=100 'FNR==NR{iplist[$1];next} /tcp/{split($5,a,":"); if (a[1] > 0 && !(a[1] in iplist)) c[a[1]]++} END{for (ip in c) if (c[ip]>max) print ip}' iplist.txt - | while read ip; do /sbin/iptables ...;done
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where to put rest of the command: | while read ip; do /sbin/iptables -m comment --comment "SCAN BLOCK" -I INPUT 1 -s $ip -j DROP; done ?

Sorry, but I am not an expert ...yet... for such "complicated" scripts :)

Comment: @Hrvoje added more details on complete command series

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about output order, why not just read in 1st `iplist.txt` into an array, as others have suggested, then just output whenever it's exactly 1 more than your `vmax` threshold, e.g. :

> ```
> # imagine the <( echo ... ) is the iplist.txt being read in
>
> jot -b '1.0.0.1' 105 | gcat -n | 
>
> mawk 'FNR==NR ? __[$(_<_)] : $NF in __  && 
>                          __[ $NF ]++==+_' \_='100' <( echo '1.0.0.1' ) -
> ```

```
101 1.0.0.1
```

**ps :** `jot -w '%d 1.0.0.1' 105` works just as well for `line 1`, but it really doesn't matter what line 1 is since it represents whatever comes in via the pipe

Comment: `gcat` is weird, the `-n` option is a non-POSIX extension, but Awk knows very well the line number, a feature you are already using.

Comment: Would also need to install **jot** and **gcat** on more than 30 nodes, and also every new node spawn...

Comment: @Hrvoje : no that's just to illustrate whatever comes in via the pipe ….. you can have microsoft word generate that input too if u like as long as it comes through the pipe as  text - since OP didn't provide a meaningful test set i had to come up with one

Comment: @tripleee: it's merely to have an external independent entity confirm the line numbers that's all …. and how does it matter that `cat -n` ain't `posix` when both `bsd-cat` and `gnu-cat` support this feature ? posix is one of the worst things that ever happened to standardization efforts across unix variants, preventing progress at every turn by still pandering to the lowest denominator of them all, even to this day. `POSIX`'s rationale of excluding `-n` `"cuz it's already offered by utility pr"` is even more non-sensical than i could possibly fathom.

Comment: `gcat` is weird becauso virtually nobody will have a command with that name. I can guess that you mean GNU `cat`, probably on a Mac with Homebrew, but many users will not. I still don't understand how this "confirms" the line numbers; do you mistrust Awk's `NR`?

Comment: @tripleee : i trust `awk`'s line numbers, but doing it this way makes it clear i didn't try to sneak in the line numbers with obscure code inside `awk - but all that is moot because no one needs to actually print out the line number, from `awk` or from `cat`, in their usage - it's merely an illustration too. and yes, i'm blessed with being on the single best cpu architecture to power any unix or linux.